# CAPS LOCK freezes mouse

Tags: counter-strike-source

After many years i reinstalled CSS on my EliteBook 8570w.

I used CAPS LOCK as jump, but on this notebook I have problems with it.
When i press CAPS lock mouse freezes for few seconds making me unable to turn.

I checked ... the sticky keys are not on and CAPS lock seems to be binded only to JUMP.

Whats the problem?

Comment: What kind of mouse do you have?

Comment: Could you not just re-bind it?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that "HP Hotkey Support" service was messing with CAPS LOCK. After disabling it from startup the CAPS-LOCK works.